# How to fix SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `categories` where `enable` = 1) on Laradock?

Tags: php, laravel, laradock

I'm trying to build laravel on docker, But when I tried to run `php artisan migrate` I got an error like this:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `categories` where `enable` = 1)

[Error in Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryYN5.png)

[Error in Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVWo4.png)

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: cilsy
      MYSQL_USER: cilsy
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel
```

this is my .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=cilsy
DB_USERNAME=cilsy
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

I have install composer `php-common` `php-mbstring` `php-xml` `php-zip` `php-json` `libmcrypt-dev` `php-curl`.

I don't know how to fix this problem, any ideas?

Comment: Try Changing "DB_HOST" in the .env file from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"

Comment: I have trying that, but nothing happen.

Answer (score 1):

Change `"DB_HOST"` in the `.env` file from `"localhost"` to `"127.0.0.1"`

I had the exact same problem. None of the above solutions worked for me. I solved the problem by changing the `"host"` in the `/app/config/database.php` file from `"localhost"` to `"127.0.0.1"`.

Comment: I have trying that, but nothing happen.

Comment: when you change your .env then clear config & cache php artisan cache:clear & php  artisan config:clear

Answer (score 1):

In my case, changing the `DB_HOST` to localhost didn't fix the issue. I had to change it to `mysql` which works fine

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you run 
`php artisan config:clear`
and restart the server

Answer (score 0):

try to **update XAMPP** or whatever server using and with the latest PHP version.

I got the same error when I shifting my project to **mac** I tried everything at last I *uninstall the XAMPP* and install the XAMPP with the latest PHP version updated version.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Open the `.env` file and change it `DB_HOST=localhost` to  `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`

- `DB_USERNAME` should be set to `root` if you do not have a default username in the installation time.
- `DB_PASSWORD`  If no password is set on the database, just clear it

After `.env` edit, must be clear cache: `php artisan config:cache`